# JSON not getting iterated in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON in which I have data for brands with the stock field coming from SOLR API call:

```
{
    response:{},
    numFound:{},
    facet_fields:{
        brand,stock:[{
            pivot:"text",
            value:"name1",
            count:"text"
        },{
            pivot:"text",
            value:"name2",
            count:"text2"
        }]
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to iterate through brand, stock in PHP by using `foreach` loop as below. It shows 500 error in browser.

I get complete JSON string with `file_get_contents()` function then decode in JSON and then I use `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($obj->facet_fields->brand,stock as $array)
{

}
```

Whereas following works, but I don't need it.

```
foreach($obj->facet_fields as $array)
{

}
```

Please help in resolving the 500 error.

Comment: What about turning on error reporting?

Comment: i tried that as well.it didnt give me the error

Comment: hw can i report the errors if its not reporting with turning error reporting on also

Comment: maybe that's not the problem, but the json you pasted is not valid, the key "brand,stock" is invalid, you can't have commas in keys

Comment: Your JSON data has invalid structure. Figure it out first.

Comment: its valid.i have pasted a specimen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a comma (,) inside the name, it will not work. Try:

`foreach($obj->facet_fields->{"brand,stock"} as $array)`